# XML Entity Mapping error in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am reading the tutorials of petri from http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-creating-database-queries-with-named-queries/ and decided to do a Proof of Concept (POC) regarding Spring Data JPA. I've created a named native query using XML and annotated my User Repository with `@Query(nativeQuery = true)`. (btw Hibernate is my JPA provider).

Here's my method in my UserRepository.java

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true)
    public User findByNameAndPasswordXml(@Param("name") String name,@Param("password") String password);
```

And Here's my orm.xml file is below and located under src/main/resources/META-INF folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">

    <named-native-query name="User.findByNameAndPasswordXml"
                result-class="org.jrue.poc.springhibernate.domain.User">
        <description>Multiple search query</description>
            <query>
                SELECT 
                    * 
                FROM 
                    M_USER
                WHERE 
                    name = :name
                    AND password = :password
            </query>
    </named-native-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

For Spring Data to work, I've specified the location in my persistence configuration using below annotation

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"org.jrue.poc.springhibernate.repository"}
                        ,namedQueriesLocation="classpath:META-INF/*.xml")
```

However when I execute my unit test, I receive the below exception which points to my orm.xml file.

```
Caused by: java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 23; Document root element "entity-mappings", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at sun.util.xml.PlatformXmlPropertiesProvider.load(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties$XmlSupport.load(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.loadFromXML(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.util.DefaultPropertiesPersister.loadFromXml(DefaultPropertiesPersister.java:78)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:91)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.createProperties(PropertiesFactoryBean.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(PropertiesFactoryBean.java:71)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 23; Document root element "entity-mappings", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source
```

Am i using wrong XML format? I've searched from the net and found no related issue with entity-mappings.

Comment: Did you try to use version="2.1" and schemaLocation=".../orm_2_1.xsd" ?

Comment: Yes, but another error show

Comment: also "java.sun.com" no longer exists ... should be like the top example on this page http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/metadata_xml.html

Comment: Thanks but same error